# unable to edit css style for tweet button

Tags: css, twitter

I am working on styling a Tweet button by modifying the CSS class using font-awesome without success. here is the HTML code taken from Twitter:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>.
```

The issue originates from the widgets.js, whenever it loads, whatever I do it will change the style to the classic one, and in case removing or bypassing "twitter-share-button" class, the button won't work anymore.

any suggestion on how to use a specific style on tweet button?

Tweet.

Comment: It looks as though the widget is placing iframes in your page so you won't get to alter the styling through your own CSS outside that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I did find a solution, although not the way I liked...
I did some modifications to the code to become as follows:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitename.com%2F&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Ebuttonembed%7Ctwterm%5Eshare%7Ctwgr%5E&text=<?php echo "$txt" ;?><?php echo "$ttr" ;?>&url=https%3A%2F%2F<?php echo "$lk" ;?>" class="fa fa-twitter"></a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

`txt = "websitename"; $ttr = urlencode("$titleforarticle") . "\n"; $lk = urlencode("$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]") . "\n";`

you may use JS instead of PHP.

better solutions are always welcome!